# CMake FeatureSummary remove some packages from the list

Tags: cmake

I have a project where I look for spdlog and, if not found, I fetch it from git using FetchContent. However I also use FeatureSummary, so when spdlog is not found, it's reported by FeatureSummary.

I don't want that FeatureSummary reports it, as I am going to download the package from git, so makes no sense to report it as not found.

However, I have some other packages which are optional and I search for them using find_package(foo QUIET), so excluding the QUIET packages from the FeatureSummary will also disable this optional packages, and I don't want that.

How can I remove spdlog from the list of not found packages that are going to be listed by FeatureSummary?

```
find_package(spdlog QUIET)
if (NOT TARGET spdlog::spdlog)
    message(STATUS "spdlog was not found. Fetching from git")

    FetchContent_Declare(
        spdlog
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
        GIT_TAG v1.8.5
        )
    set(SPDLOG_INSTALL ON CACHE BOOL "Install spdlog" FORCE)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spdlog)
endif()
```

Comment: I guess try something along `get_property(tmp GLOBAL PROPERTY PACKAGES_FOUND)` `list(FILTER PACKAGES_FOUND spdlog)` `set_property(PACKAGES_FOUND GLOBAL_PROPERTY ${tmp})`

Comment: This is not exactly the correct syntax, but points me on the right direction to do it. thanks